# Whats the dfference between ||= and |= with booleans

Tags: ruby, boolean, assign

I understand that `a ||= b` behaves like `a || a = b` and that `a |= b` behaves like `a = a | b`

When working with booleans, does it make a difference which you use? I presume that the only practical difference is that `||=` will not assign if `a` and `b` are true, is that the only difference?

Comment: The *abbreviated assignments* `a ||= b` and `a |= b` (which respectively expand to `a = a || b` and `a = a | b`) are as different as `a += b` and `a -= b`. The choice between `||` and `|` depends on what is wanted. The fact that the methods have a superficial similarity (one vs. two pipes) is irrelvant, as it is when comparing `=`, `==` and `===`.

Comment: `||` is a logical operator provided by the language itself whereas `|` is a plain method call provided by the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not quite right. In general the `X=` operator behaves like `A = A X B` where `X` is one of the supported operators. Notably it's always on the right side of the `=`.

That being said, `|` and `||` are two *very* different operators. The `|` version is typically understood to do **binary math**, as in:

```
2 | 1
# => 3
```

Where that's the result of `0b10` and `0b01` being combined with a binary OR.

It also does array unions:

```
[ 1, 2 ] | [ 2, 3 ]
# => [ 1, 2, 3 ]
```

Whereas `||` a higher level logical test on the *truthiness* of values. In Ruby only `nil` and `false` are considered *non-truthful*, all other values are considered *truthful*, so:

```
0 || 1
# => 0
false || true
# => true
nil || "yes"
# => "yes"
```

The same principle applies to `&` and `&&`.

Interestingly `|` and `&` are method calls and their actual functionality depends on what's on the left side of the operator, while `||` and `&&` are syntactic elements you cannot change and always work the same way.

So where do `|=` and `||=` come into play? There's a few cases where you'll see them.

Setting bitflags:

```
flags |= 0b0010
```

Applying defaults:

```
max ||= MAX_DEFAULT
```

Answer (score 1):

While `Oring` if any statement is `true` then completed statement will return `true` only.
Similarly, while `Anding` if any statement is `false` then completed statement will return `false` only.

The major difference between `||` & `|` is when first statement of `||` is `truthy` the other statements not execute. Whereas `|` will execute all the statements even if the first statements is `truthy`.

Consider following example for `||`

```
2.6.5 :001 > a = 4
 => 4
2.6.5 :002 > a ||= (b = 9) # same as a = 4 || 9
 => 4
2.6.5 :003 > a
 => 4
2.6.5 :004 > b
 => nil
```

example for `|` (For `int | other_int` it will do the `bitwise OR` [ref](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Integer.html#method-i-7C) )

```
2.6.5 :005 > c = 6
 => 6
2.6.5 :006 > c |= (d = 8) # same as a = 0110 || 1110
 => 14
2.6.5 :007 > c
 => 14
2.6.5 :008 > d
 => 8
```

**For Boolean**
Example for `||`

```
2.6.5 :001 > a = true
 => true
2.6.5 :002 > a ||= (b = false)
 => true
2.6.5 :003 > a
 => true
2.6.5 :004 > b
 => nil
```

Example for `|`

```
2.6.5 :005 > c = true
 => true
2.6.5 :006 > c |= (d = false)
 => true
2.6.5 :007 > c
 => true
2.6.5 :008 > d
 => false
```